# facebook App with PHP SDK cannot get User ID in IE 8

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-8, facebook-php-sdk

In my facebook App, I am submitting the form to the same page.
After submitted, I will check the user is logged in by getUser(). If a user id can be got, POST data will be stored to database.
The below code works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari in Both Mac and PC.
However, when I first submit the form in IE 8, getUser() will return 0. Then I submit the form again, the user ID can be got.
I have not idea why the user ID cannot be got at the first submission. Can anyone help?
Thanks!

```
<?php
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
?>

<form action="" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">
...
</form>
```

Comment: _Third party cookies_ – again …?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the rest of code, but if you ask is you has $user, or not you have to request autentification or login. there is something like this:

```
if(!$user) make the login request
else continuos with your code.
```

sees the sdk php code or javascript library for Facebook in the Facebook developer side.

other problem is possible that you have and error while you try to get the user, and its possible you have to do a

```
try{
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
}catch (exception *e){
//is there is and error you have to login again to get the users data
}
```

I hoper this will be useful for you